# Nuclear Physics - Half life and radioactivity

Tags: nuclear-physics

Why do materials not remain radioactive?
What happens at the end of a radioactive substances half life?

Comment: Take this analogy for radio activity: Consider a bunch of marbles bound by rubber band(s). Every once in a while it happens that a marble breaks free and flies off. this process of marbles flying off is radio activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Materials do not remain radioactive forever. And, nothing special happens at the "end" of the halflife.

When an atom undergoes radioactive decay, it changes from one element into another. If the new element is not radioactive, that is the end of the line for that particular atom. If the new element is also radioactive, then it will decay further, until a stable element is reached. At that point, this atom stops changing.

The halflife of an element is the time period in which half the atoms in a sample decay. Radioactive decay is completely statistical: there is no way anyone can predict when a specific atom will decay. All we can say that in a given time period a certain fraction will undergo decay. The halflife is that time after which 50% of the atoms have decayed.

Hence, at the end of the halflife, all that has happens is that 50% of the atoms have decayed. The other 50% are still decaying at the same rate. Of course, as there are only 50% of the atoms remaining, the activity of the sample has also been reduced by 50%. After another halflife, half of these remaining atoms will have decayed, so only 25% are left. This continues until, eventually, there is only 1 atom left. This one will sit around for an unknown time (remember, we cannot predict when it will decay). When it finally decays, all the original atoms will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Unstable nuclei decay finally forming stage nuclei in the case which is $^{206}_{\;82}\rm Pb$ in this case.

[image]

The time which are shown indicate the half life of the radioisotope.
On average after one half life half of a particular species of radioisotope would have decayed.
After about 10 half lives roughly $\left( \dfrac 12\right)^{10}=0.1\%$ of the radioisotope is left.

Here is a decay scheme for another radioisotope which is present in your body.

[image]

In this case the unstable Potassium-40 nucleus ends up as either a Calcium-40 or Argon-40 nucleus both of which are stable.